# What is the amount of EM energy from the sun reaching the earth as a function of wavelength?

Tags: energy, visible-light, infrared-radiation

The question stems from a desire to know if more light from the sun in the infrared wavelengths has more energy than light at say yellow or violet wavelengths - at the Earth's surface.  I'm guessing a simple 2-D graph would illustrate the answer well.

Comment: Have you asked Google for the solar spectrum at sea level?  There are many images.  http://www.theoildrum.com/node/4964 might be what you want  A similar figure is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_spectrum with more information

Comment: No.  I had searched other things. Thank you for the links.